# how can I trigger dayRender to update fullcalender cells to update cell contents

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to update cell contents in fullcalender after I update the events using click/drag drop/move. The events are updated with the new data but I also want to re-render day cell contents.

I tried

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'render' );
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'dayRender' );
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'viewRender' );
```

But days (cells in calender table) contents are not updated. I have customized cell using `dayRender( date, cell );` callback but it is triggered only when fullcalender is rendered first time. How can I trigger it anywhere else in my code to re-render the whole calender?

Comment: update: This screenshot may be helpful [link](http://s7.postimg.org/yn4y8ocmj/full_calender_noway_to_trigger_day_Render.png)

Answer (score 5):

Do a prev & next and the calendar will be rendered, the full calendar is "smart" enough not to re-render cells in the same view.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('prev');
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('next');
```

Comment: My tests might be flawed (I'm new to the plug-in) but if you've defined the `events` property this will trigger two additional AJAX requests (or will enter an infinite loop if you aren't careful).

Answer (score 0):

@danish , i think u have to use "addEventSource".

[check this link](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/addEventSource/)

**sample code:**

// inside ajax success callback

```
$.map(data, function (me) {

                  me.start = moment(me.start).format();
                  me.end = moment(me.end).format();
}

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);
```

this will also calls the EventRender and EventAfterRender callback where usually we customize the events..

Comment: The events are loaded/updated correctly but not the days. I have custom labels for each day of calender. On updating events, days must also update. see screenshot: http://s7.postimg.org/yn4y8ocmj/full_calender_noway_to_trigger_day_Render.png